# How to get current month from the selected date in GWT?

Tags: gwt

```
        Date startDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(""05/07/2018")getValue().toString());
```

> get last day of selected month is required

```
  private Date lastDayOfMonth(Date month) {
    Date lastDay = (Date) month.clone();
    CalendarUtil.addMonthsToDate(lastDay, 1);
    CalendarUtil.setToFirstDayOfMonth(lastDay);
    CalendarUtil.addDaysToDate(lastDay, -1);
    GWT.log("lastDay :: "+lastDay);
    return lastDay;
}
```

> I get lastDay :: Tue Jul 31 00:00:00 GMT+530 2018
>   But i get 30th instead of 31st

Answer (score 0):

First, your code does not work

```
Date startDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(""05/07/2018")getValue().toString());
```

Second, your method `private Date lastDayOfMonth(Date month)` looks fine, I have a test and got result Tue Jul 31 00:00:00

I dont understand your problem "Tue Jul 31 00:00:00 GMT+530 2018 But i get 30th instead of 31st". How can you get 30th from Tue Jul 31 00:00:00 GMT+530?